# .net core project cannot load assemblies in linux docker container

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core

I have the following issue: I have one project which loads another project using `Assembly.LoadFile()`. Everything works fine on windows but when i try to run it using docker it fails, saying `Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '/app/HellowWorldProject.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

My findings are that the .dll file i'm searching for is in the same directory it is searched but something fails somewhere. On the image you can see that the file exists in /app directory in the docker container. The code i execute and the dockerfile can be found in my github: https://github.com/andre197/DebugDotNetCoreInDockerTest . Can anyone help me with that issue? [image]

Comment: Did you check the path to the file for case sensitiveness? it is important in Linux and probably your path have something that is camel case or something like that.Eventually Linux container cannot find the path.

Comment: The whole path is shown in the image attached to the question. The file it searches for has absolutely the same name and path and the same case as it is in the container. It is event marked with the red rectangles, so that is not the case

Comment: You have one additional w in your file name.check it again

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome. I posted summary of my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish your project **from windows to Linux containers** , you should pay attention to path because in Linux based operating systems, **case sensitiveness of path** to file is important.
Absolutley if you have mismatch in your path to file, you got file not found error